# Flutter- Creating an android emulator for my app

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

I wrote an app, and now I want to test on a Android environment,but when I press debug, no emulator is shown. I clicked on create new emulator, and It says creating new emulator, but nothing happens after that. Also, I tried to connect my phone to use it as an emulator but It wasn't being found by visual studio code. I am a beginner so please, any helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall flutter SDK and don't forget to install flutter plugin on your editor (Android Studio or VsCode), Depending on your OS follow one of this instruction, it's so simple to install.

https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install